# Get/Set is not a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a class which contains some get/set functions. I am facing an issue where the set function is not working. The class looks like this:

```
export class Item {
    private _someProp: any;

    constructor() {
        this._someProp = [];
    }

    get SomeProp(): any {
        return this._someProp;
    }

    set SomeProp(value: any) {
        this._someProp = value;
    }
}
```

Later in the code when I do this:

```
let obj = new Item();
obj.SomeProp([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

The browser says: `obj.SomeProp is not a function`

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Why was the tag changed from TypeScript to JavaScript?  The original tag was perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a property, so assign to it.

```
obj.SomeProp = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```